# jquery validate-plugin required( dependency-expression )

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a problem with my address data. So either you enter a new address (all of the fields are inputfields except gender,selection, it's a radiobutton), or you select an address from a given list, so if you want the one from the list(selected with a radiobutton -> `input[@name='select_address'])`, all the inputfields are not required anymore ...

```
rules: {
delivery_gender: 
        {required:"input[@name='select_address'].not(':checked')"}
```

So the field `gender` should only be required if the input select-field `(input[@name='select_address)` is not checked. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried another way:

```
$('input:radio[name=select_address]').click(function() {
    delivery_gender.rules('remove');
```

but it won't work either. Any ideas?

The problem only comes up with the radiobuttons because for the input-fields i just removed the class:

```
$('input.delivery').removeClass('required error');
```

Comment: For `rules: { myfield: {required:`, the only acceptable parameter is `true` or `false`.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: This sentence is garbled and needs to be fixed... _"So either you enter a new address, or you select an already once before entered address"_

Comment: @Sparky672: i don't think so, or the documentation is wrong: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required, check chapter required( dependency-expression ), the validation should work like this: you enter a new address, but there are also former entered addresses listet, so if you choose one of these, all the inputfields loose the need to be validated. with the textinputs i solved it with removeClass, but it's not working for the gener select-radiobuttons...

Comment: Okay- I see now.  I think you're going to have to post a little HTML too because the question is still not clear.

Comment: @sinini does my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [dependancy callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback) :

```
required: function(element) {
    return $("input[name=select_adddress]:checked").val() == "custom";
}
```

This checks if the value of the checked radio button in the group `select_address` is equal to custom - if it is then the gender field is required.

[working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6YMX4/1/) - in the example you need to select `custom` to make the `gender` field required.

Comment: that's almost what i need, but it should be required, if the select_address is NOT checked... i'm afraid i have something wrong in my logic: http://jsfiddle.net/6YMX4/9/

Comment: @sinini its a radio group - checking either will make it checked ... in my example you check which one is checked using `.val()` - can you include your HTML output in your question

Comment: have you seen the modified code here jsfiddle.net/6YMX4/9? if none of the radiobuttons is selected, the gender-input should be required, so i need something like the .is(":not(:checked)"), but it's not working... thank you so much for your help

Comment: it's not updating: when i first try to send it empty, the error appears but doesn't disappear, when i check a selectbox, only after buttonclick..., because of this, i still have the error in my project (i think =)

Comment: @sinini Try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/6YMX4/15/ have to add an extra check for `click` on radio

Comment: i'm really sorry for wasting your time, but its not working... when i use this, nothing happens, always the same error

Comment: finally i solved it in a really strange way, inserting a hidden radiobutton which always was checked, when none of the name=select_adddress was checked, and which was unchecked as soon as one of the name=select_adddress was selected, and than, i got it working with this: rules: {delivery_gender:required:"input#checkoffgender:checked"}. i think, there is no possibility to enter a :not:checked... so i took this way, but thanks a lot for helping me